# Get the sum of all rows in one table

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I've tried to get the sum of all rows from one table with the following code, but sadly my database gives me "NULL" back.

PHP:

```
$get_cash=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(price) FROM products WHERE ID='$F_User_ID'"); 
$fetch_cash = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_cash); 
$cash = $fetch_cash["cash"]; 
echo "<p>Money spent already: $cash €</p>";
```

MySQL:

```
MariaDB [database]> SELECT SUM(price) FROM products WHERE ID='100001';
+------------+
| SUM(price) |
+------------+
|       NULL |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I want to get the sum of how much money the Person F_User_ID has already spent in all products he has bought.

Comment: Can you post the full PHP code?

Comment: $get_cash=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(price) AS total FROM products WHERE ID='$F_User_ID'");
    $fetch_cash = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_cash);
    $cash = $fetch_cash["cash"];

echo "<p>Money spent already: $cash €</p>";

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code. It's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Anyways, you're looking for an alias called 'cash' but your query does not contain that alias.

Comment: `cash` vs `total`

Comment: Thanks already for your help. But then why does mysql give back "NULL" when I ask it for the sum

Comment: the total was just a try, not used in the code at the beginning.
Still I think the issue is on mysql, otherwise I should have gotten back a result, not Null, right?

Comment: I expect your `error_reporting` not being set to ALL, so the Notice 'undefined Index' will be hidden (which would be there for `$fetch_cash["cash"];`).

Comment: does `SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID='100001';` return anything?

Comment: it returns "NULL" as stated above. Thats my issue I have.

Comment: You don't have an identifier for 'cash' like you try to use `$fetch_cash["cash"]`. Change your query to `SELECT SUM(price) AS cash` and that will give you something to attach to.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: read what i wrote again `SELECT * ..` not `SELECT SUM(` ...

Comment: tried it with "select SUM(price) AS cash", still no luck
fetch_cash["price"] did also not the trick

Comment: SELECT * ... did return my products I have

Comment: What type of field is price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace a NULL with a zero, and we can assign an *alias* to the expression to be used as the column name in the resultset. If this query executes, it will return a single row containing a column named `cash`.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price),0) AS `cash` FROM products WHERE id = 'someval'
```

---

Recommended reading:

Exploits of a Mom:  https://xkcd.com/327/  aka Little Bobby Tables

OWASP SQL Injection:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Fixed it, now when I have two products it displays the correct sum, thanks a lot!

Comment: Run a query without the SUM() aggregate, Return just the `price` column. Are there any rows returned that have a non-NULL value for `price`? Are there any rows returned? NULL is a valid return for the SUM() aggregate in cases where there are no non-NULL values for `price` returned.